# How I hide default legend?

Tags: charts, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I want to define conditional legend. I give a colour to one thing. but when my report is running, yes the colour is setting but in a legend show different colour to same thing.In chart it shows colour which I want but in a legend it shows up different colour which in normal palette. how can i fix this ? thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack I would use would be in-line CSS hiding the legend element.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug! You can hide the default legend and put customised legends(images) out of the chart. I didn't get another solution. []'s